# Calling Cloud Function from App Engine runtime Python 3.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I have an App Engine service, running Python 3.7, that needs to call and get a response from one of my Cloud Functions via the `https.oncall` trigger.

I thought I could do so with the following:

```
import logging
from sys import exit

import firebase_admin

import requests

import google.cloud.logging
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()

firebase_admin.initialize_app()

response = requests.post("https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/functionname", data={"foo": "bar"})

if response.status_code != 200:
    exit("Could not call function! :(") # This is happening

logging.info(f"Yay! Here is the result: {response.text}")

# do something else

exit()
```

However, I'm getting `Request has incorrect Content-Type.` from Cloud Functions.

I've tried multiple variations on the request syntax such as: `data='{"foo": "bar"}'` and `data=json.dumps({"foo": "bar"})` but all I can get back is either `Request has incorrect Content-Type.` or `Request has incorrect Content-Type. application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

How do I properly attach my dictionary to my request so that the function receives it in the form of `application/json` as noted [in the Cloud Function docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference)?

I've read other posts that suggest using the `json.dumps()` function will tell `request` to use `application/json` but Cloud Functions wasn't happy about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the `Content-Type` for your request. Starting with `requests==2.4.2`, you can use the `json` parameter instead to pass a dictionary and automatically set the `Content-Type`:

```py
requests.post(url, json={"foo": "bar"})
```