# Authorise a HTTP Triggered Cloud Function from a (Python 2.7) App Engine instance, using a service worker account

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We have an HTTP triggered Cloud Function that has permissions set up via IAM. From our Python App Engine, how do we invoke the cloud function using a GCP Service Account?

Using the cloud functions service, we are able to call:

```
functions_service.projects().locations().functions().call(name=function_name)
```

This works, as the service adds the Bearer Authentication HTTP header. However, according to the docs ([here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call)), using the call() method to invoke the cloud function means we have a strict rate limit of 16/100s which is not suitable for production.

If we try calling the cloud function directly, via the https://[region]-[projectId].cloudfunctions.net/[functionName] URL, it does not authenticate (responds with 401), even with the Bearer Authentication HTTP header described above.

Comment: Where are you seeing this quota limit? The invoke quota is 100,000,000 per 100 seconds. https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits

Comment: @JohnHanley in the link you provided under "API calls (CALL)"

Comment: For what you mention, what you are trying to achieve is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54777411/calling-cloud-function-from-app-engine-runtime-python-3-7), if you need to use a service account, I would recommend just to authenticate it in the application when you are going to call the function